# Using Matlab from c# update variable issue

Tags: c#, matlab, random, callback

In the code I shared below I am using matlab dll from c# application.The values returned by matlab object are random variables so I am expecting them to change at different calls.
In Matlab it is working normally( returning different values in each call) but when I click the button again it is returning the same values

Here , powerRecLog() should return different value but whenever I click button again

onum.lqia,onum.lqib,onum.lqic,onum.lqid is not changing.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Yeni Olcum
        {
            var acCtx = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("matlab.application.single");
            var matlab = (MLApp.MLApp)Activator.CreateInstance(acCtx);
            matlab.Visible = 0;
            matlab.PutWorkspaceData("Pr", "base", 0);
            onum = new OnlineOlcum();
            try
            {
                onum.xpos = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
                onum.ypos = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
                label1.Text += " " + onum.xpos + "   " + onum.ypos + "\n";

            double t1, t2, t3, t4;
            t1 = Math.Round(T1.Mesafe(onum), 8);
            t2 = Math.Round(T2.Mesafe(onum), 8);
            t3 = Math.Round(T3.Mesafe(onum), 8);
            t4 = Math.Round(T4.Mesafe(onum), 8);

            string s1, s2, s3, s4;
            s1 = t1.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US"));
            s2 = t2.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US"));
            s3 = t3.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US"));
            s4 = t4.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US"));

            matlab.Execute("Pr=PowerRecLog(" + s1 + ",1,160,1);");
            onum.lqia = Math.Round((double)matlab.GetVariable("Pr", "base"), 8);
            matlab.Execute("Pr=PowerRecLog(" + s2 + ",1,160,1);");
            onum.lqib = Math.Round((double)matlab.GetVariable("Pr", "base"), 8);
            matlab.Execute("Pr=PowerRecLog(" + s3 + ",1,160,1);");
            onum.lqic = Math.Round((double)matlab.GetVariable("Pr", "base"), 8);
            matlab.Execute("Pr=PowerRecLog(" + s4 + ",1,160,1);");
            onum.lqid = Math.Round((double)matlab.GetVariable("Pr", "base"), 8);

        }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            matlab.Quit();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour that you describe above (the repeated values returned by MATLAB) may make sense.   Your code above seems to create a new instance of MATLAB whenever the `button1_Click` function is called.  The code then builds and invokes the (MATLAB?) function `PowerRecLog` that generates some numbers that you expect to be random but are not - they repeat at each call to `button1_Click`.  Presumably the body of `PowerRecLog` use the MATLAB `rand`, `randn`, or `randi` pseudorandom number generators.

If I launch MATLAB from my desktop and type `rand(50,1)`, I will get a 50x1 matrix of uniformly distributed pseudo random numbers.  If I exit MATLAB, re-launch it and type the command `rand(50,1)` I get the **same** 50 uniformly distributed pseudo random numbers!

According to the MATLAB documentation ([why do random numbers repeat after startup](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/why-do-random-numbers-repeat-after-startup.html)) the random number generator (that all rand functions draw random numbers from) resets itself to the same state at startup.

To get around this (see same link), you can control the random number generation by invoking `rng('shuffle')` which seeds the random number generator based on the current time so that the rand functions produce different sequences of numbers after each time you call **rng**.

So each time the `button1_Click` is invoked, you can call (in MATLAB) the `rng('shuffle')` to reseed the random number generator.  Or, add this command to the MATLAB `startup.m` file to have this automatically happen each time MATLAB is launched.